# iPhone provisioning first time try problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, provisioning

This is my first try in moving my app to a device. I was able to launch the app by clicking on the start button on XCode to launch it on my iPhone. I stopped the app and see if I want to try whether I am able to run it without being plugged. I can still see the app icon on my iPhone but when I launch it.. it immediately closes. What am I doing wrong?

I fixed the error, it was a stupid %@ where I need %f.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not related to provisioning. Environment is different when the program is being debugged. Plug the iPhone back to computer and check the crash log in **XCode > Organizer > Device > Device Log**.

Comment: @EquinoX: Good to hear that the problem is fixed.

Answer (score 3):

First delete your application from the device and run again your application from the XCode on the device and run it thoroughly while the device is connected and then try to run the application. It should then work.